# duplicate symbols for architecture libcordova.a

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We're using Worklight (using cordova) we're building a hybrid project for android and iOS.

We recently upgraded the SDK to iOS8.3 and we started getting the following errors which prevent us from building.
I wonder if this is common to others and if anyone has a hint on how to solve this.

(We've been through a full delete of the iPhone environment and a recreation of the environment from scratch but the problem persists)

**UPDATE**: Attaching also the build settings and build phases screens.

[image: duplicate symbols for architecture libcordova.a]

[image: Build settings]

[image: Build phases]

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you have `libcordova` linked twice, check the `build phases` tab, and/or the `other linker flags` setting in `build settings`, you'll likely find more than one reference to the problematic library.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work: I can't remove it from the "link binary libraries" cause then it's missing. And removing it from the linker flags doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: Can you add to the question screenshots of your build settings and build phases, highlighting the cordova usage?

Comment: Not sure how to post an image in a comment so I'll post it to the question above...

Comment: Couldn't tell much from the two images, due to the scaling, however here's another suggestion: `build settings` and `build phases` each has a search box, write `cordova` there and see in how many places it appears.

Comment: The search didn't show any duplicates... So, finally we had to turn to "brute force"... seeing as a fresh new "helloWorld" project was working and building fine, we copied the original project's files, selectively, onto the working "helloWorld" and it's OK now... I can only regret that we didn't manage to get down to the bottom of it, but at least this time-sucking nightmare is over... Thanks for you help mate!

Comment: It might have been for other libraries to statically link to `libcordova`, however that harder to hunt :) Or perhaps some parts of the `cordova` source code were part of the project, thus also generating some of the `cordova` functions. Anyhow, glad you get rid of the problem, one way or another.